# Joomla constant to current template path

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, module-params, images

I am developing a custom module, and I need this module to show selected some pictures selected in the backend. So, I declare a parameter with type "imagelist" in my module xml file.

```
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">
            <field
                name="project1-image"
                type="imagelist"
                directory="???\images"
                label="..."
                description="..." />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
```

The problem is the "images" directory is located in some Joomla template. Is there some constant like "JPATH_COMPONENT" or "JPATH_BASE" pointing to currently applied template to site? Or do I need to force site admin to write filename and find it in php file of my module (which seems like a bad solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter a directory value, it will be relative to the root of you Joomla installation. Thus, if you want to get images from your template, simply use the following:

```
directory="templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/images"
```

This can only be used for a predefined template and **cannot** be used for the *current* template.

For this, you will need to create a custom form field. I would suggest copying the `imagelist` form field and changing the paths

Comment: bad... but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7):

Look at https://gist.github.com/leFlea-snippets/4602845

PHP: Joomla - Get active template path

```
// Get active template path from anywhere on Joomla: 
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$path   = JURI::base(true).'/templates/'.$app->getTemplate().'/';
```